# Python saving data and retrieving it

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to make a python program that lets you track how much certain people owe you. It should ask you your name and the people's names the first time it is run. Afterwards it should say something along the lines of "Welcome back (name)" and be able to retrieve the people's names and how much they owe you, as well as allowing the user to edit names/owed money etc. 
However, this wasn't mentioned in any of the tutorials I did. I have no idea how to even start. Is there a library or something for this? I tried using text files but it didn't work. What is the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: Show us what you tried with text files :)

Comment: Try the [pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) module.

Comment: @hiragana  Can you let us know how much Python experience you have?  Programming experience in general?  I have the impression the people who is answering your question is assuming way too different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program should:

1. Check if a file (with a fixed filename) exists (or has any contents).
2. If it does not exist, then obtain data from the user and save it in the file.
3. If it does exist, read it.  Display it to the user.  Ask the user an input of "quit" (to exit) or a person name.  If a person name, ask the user for the change in balance (positive number= a new loan; negative number= payback).

Before you start, it's better you define a data model for the application, i.e. what data you need to store, and how you will store it.  Would you use lists?  Dictionaries?  Sets?  Would you create objects?  You also need to consider how to store this information in a file.  You can do this by yourself or use the `pickle` module or similar.  If you are just learning the language, I would recommend to do it yourself.

Comment: what do you mean by do it yourself?

Comment: @hiragana  Basically reading and/or writing to files without using any of the libraries mentioned by @Wolph, but simpler mechanisms (standard functions like `open` and module `io`).

Answer (score 0):

Anything within this section of the documentation: http://docs.python.org/2/library/persistence.html

- cPickle — Python object serialization
- shelve — Python object persistence
- marshal — Internal Python object serialization
- anydbm — Generic access to DBM-style databases
- whichdb — Guess which DBM module created a database
- dbm — Simple “database” interface
- gdbm — GNU’s reinterpretation of dbm
- dbhash — DBM-style interface to the BSD database library
- bsddb — Interface to Berkeley DB library
- dumbdbm — Portable DBM implementation
- sqlite3 — DB-API 2.0 interface for SQLite databases

Or just get any database. That can be done really easily given an ORM library like SQLAlchemy.

Comment: but seriously I have no idea what half that means

Comment: @hiragana: your use case sounds perfect for a database, but pretty much all of these solutions could be used but have varying amounts of complexity. If the project is small and expected to stay small... you can try any of the ones above. If you expect it to grow, take a look at an ORM